# Express $\sec^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $\cos^{-1}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to algebraically solve for $x$ in $\sec(x)=\pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$ . My first step was to isolate $x$ by making the equation into $x=\sec^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$ . Now I only have the <kbd>sin</kbd>, <kbd>cot</kbd> and <kbd>tan</kbd> keys on my calculator, as well as their inverses (e.g. $\sin^{-1}$). So, how would I express $\sec^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$ in terms of $\cos^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$ , in such a way that I could solve the initial problem using only my hand calculator and some physical writing material?

Using the online desmos calculator, I can see that the graphs for $\sec^{-1}(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\cos^{-1}(x)}$ have completely different graphs, so I'm assuming they are not equal to one another.

Comment: $\sec\theta=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\iff\cos\theta=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Know your trig values at special angles?

Comment: Probably not in terms of $\cos^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{2\sqrt3}3\right)$, which is not real.

Comment: @peterwhy LOL, I am dumb. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$
\sec\theta={2\over\sqrt3}
$$
then
$$
\cos\theta={1\over\sec\theta}={\sqrt3\over2}
$$
so
$$
\theta=\sec^{-1}\left({2\over\sqrt3}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left({\sqrt3\over2}\right)
$$
In this case, $\theta=\pm30^\circ+n\times 360^\circ$, where $n$ is any integer.

In general, if $\sec\theta=x$ then $\cos\theta=1/x$, so
$$
\theta=\sec^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\left({1\over x}\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\sec^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg)$